# Magento 2.2 is not working in PHP 7.2.0

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.2

I am working on **Magento 2.2**.
Recently I updated my PHP version to **7.2.0**, then i am facing the Warning like this:
[image: Magento-error]

My **file.php** is :

```
<?php
/*
==New BSD License==

Copyright (c) 2012, Colin Mollenhour
All rights reserved.

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
      documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    * The name of Colin Mollenhour may not be used to endorse or promote products
      derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
    * The class name must remain as Cm_Cache_Backend_File.


 */

/**
 * Cm_Cache_Backend_File
 *
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2013 Colin Mollenhour (http://colin.mollenhour.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
class Cm_Cache_Backend_File extends Zend_Cache_Backend_File
{

    /** @var array */
    protected $_options = array(
        'cache_dir' => null,               // Path to cache files
        'file_name_prefix' => 'cm',        // Prefix for cache directories created
        'file_locking' => true,            // Best to keep enabled
        'read_control' => false,           // Use a checksum to detect corrupt data
        'read_control_type' => 'crc32',    // If read_control is enabled, which checksum algorithm to use
        'hashed_directory_level' => 2,     // How many characters should be used to create sub-directories
        'use_chmod' => FALSE,              // Do not use chmod on files and directories (should use umask() to control permissions)
        'directory_mode' => 0770,          // Filesystem permissions for created directories (requires use_chmod)
        'file_mode' => 0660,               // Filesystem permissions for created files (requires use_chmod)
    );

    /** @var bool */
    protected $_isTagDirChecked;

    /**
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        // Magento-friendly cache dir
        if (empty($options['cache_dir']) && class_exists('Mage', false)) {
            $options['cache_dir'] = Mage::getBaseDir('cache');
        }

        // Backwards compatibility ZF 1.11 and ZF 1.12
        if (isset($options['hashed_directory_umask'])) {
            $options['directory_mode'] = $options['hashed_directory_umask'];
        }
        if (isset($options['cache_file_umask'])) {
            $options['file_mode'] = $options['cache_file_umask'];
        }

        // Auto-enable chmod if modes are specified.
        if (isset($options['directory_mode']) || isset($options['file_mode'])) {
            $options['use_chmod'] = TRUE;
        }

        // Don't use parent constructor
        while (list($name, $value) = each($options)) {
            $this->setOption($name, $value);
        }

        // Check cache dir
        if ($this->_options['cache_dir'] !== null) { // particular case for this option
            $this->setCacheDir($this->_options['cache_dir']);
        } else {
            $this->setCacheDir(self::getTmpDir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, false);
        }

        // Validate prefix
        if (isset($this->_options['file_name_prefix'])) { // particular case for this option
            if (!preg_match('~^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$~D', $this->_options['file_name_prefix'])) {
                Zend_Cache::throwException('Invalid file_name_prefix : must use only [a-zA-Z0-9_]');
            }
        }

        // See #ZF-4422
        if (is_string($this->_options['directory_mode'])) {
            $this->_options['directory_mode'] = octdec($this->_options['directory_mode']);
        }
        if (is_string($this->_options['file_mode'])) {
            $this->_options['file_mode'] = octdec($this->_options['file_mode']);
        }
        $this->_options['hashed_directory_umask'] = $this->_options['directory_mode'];
        $this->_options['cache_file_umask'] = $this->_options['file_mode'];
    }

    /**
     * Test if a cache is available for the given id and (if yes) return it (false else)
     *
     * @param string $id cache id
     * @param boolean $doNotTestCacheValidity if set to true, the cache validity won't be tested
     * @return string|bool cached datas
     */
    public function load($id, $doNotTestCacheValidity = false)
    {
        $file = $this->_file($id);
        $cache = $this->_getCache($file, true);
        if ( ! $cache) {
            return false;
        }
        list($metadatas, $data) = $cache;
        if ( ! $doNotTestCacheValidity && (time() > $metadatas['expire'])) {
            // ?? $this->remove($id);
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->_options['read_control']) {
            $hashData = $this->_hash($data, $this->_options['read_control_type']);
            $hashControl = $metadatas['hash'];
            if ($hashData != $hashControl) {
                // Problem detected by the read control !
                $this->_log('Zend_Cache_Backend_File::load() / read_control : stored hash and computed hash do not match');
                $this->remove($id);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Save some string datas into a cache record
     *
     * Note : $data is always "string" (serialization is done by the
     * core not by the backend)
     *
     * @param  string $data             Datas to cache
     * @param  string $id               Cache id
     * @param  array  $tags             Array of strings, the cache record will be tagged by each string entry
     * @param  bool|int $specificLifetime If != false, set a specific lifetime for this cache record (null => infinite lifetime)
     * @return boolean true if no problem
     */
    public function save($data, $id, $tags = array(), $specificLifetime = false)
    {
        $file = $this->_file($id);
        $path = $this->_path($id);
        if ($this->_options['hashed_directory_level'] > 0) {
            if (!is_writable($path)) {
                // maybe, we just have to build the directory structure
                $this->_recursiveMkdirAndChmod($id);
            }
            if (!is_writable($path)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if ($this->_options['read_control']) {
            $hash = $this->_hash($data, $this->_options['read_control_type']);
        } else {
            $hash = '';
        }
        $metadatas = array(
            'hash' => $hash,
            'mtime' => time(),
            'expire' => $this->_expireTime($this->getLifetime($specificLifetime)),
            'tags' => implode(',', $tags),
        );
        $res = $this->_filePutContents($file, serialize($metadatas)."\n".$data);
        $res = $res && $this->_updateIdsTags(array($id), $tags, 'merge');
        return $res;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a cache record
     *
     * @param  string $id cache id
     * @return boolean true if no problem
     */
    public function remove($id)
    {
        $file = $this->_file($id);
        $metadatas = $this->_getCache($file, false);
        if ($metadatas) {
            $boolRemove   = $this->_remove($file);
            $boolTags     = $this->_updateIdsTags(array($id), explode(',', $metadatas['tags']), 'diff');
            return $boolRemove && $boolTags;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Clean some cache records
     *
     * Available modes are :
     * 'all' (default)  => remove all cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * 'old'            => remove too old cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * 'matchingTag'    => remove cache entries matching all given tags
     *                     ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     * 'notMatchingTag' => remove cache entries not matching one of the given tags
     *                     ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     * 'matchingAnyTag' => remove cache entries matching any given tags
     *                     ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     *
     * @param string $mode
     * @param array $tags
     * @return boolean true if no problem
     */
    public function clean($mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, $tags = array())
    {
        // We use this protected method to hide the recursive stuff
        clearstatcache();
        switch($mode) {
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL:
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_OLD:
                return $this->_clean($this->_options['cache_dir'], $mode);
            default:
                return $this->_cleanNew($mode, $tags);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of stored tags
     *
     * @return array array of stored tags (string)
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        $prefix = $this->_tagFile('');
        $prefixLen = strlen($prefix);
        $tags = array();
        foreach (@glob($prefix . '*') as $tagFile) {
            $tags[] = substr($tagFile, $prefixLen);
        }
        return $tags;
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of stored cache ids which match given tags
     *
     * In case of multiple tags, a logical AND is made between tags
     *
     * @param array $tags array of tags
     * @return array array of matching cache ids (string)
     */
    public function getIdsMatchingTags($tags = array())
    {
        return $this->_getIdsByTags(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG, $tags);
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of stored cache ids which don't match given tags
     *
     * In case of multiple tags, a logical OR is made between tags
     *
     * @param array $tags array of tags
     * @return array array of not matching cache ids (string)
     */
    public function getIdsNotMatchingTags($tags = array())
    {
        return $this->_getIdsByTags(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_NOT_MATCHING_TAG, $tags);
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of stored cache ids which match any given tags
     *
     * In case of multiple tags, a logical AND is made between tags
     *
     * @param array $tags array of tags
     * @return array array of any matching cache ids (string)
     */
    public function getIdsMatchingAnyTags($tags = array())
    {
        return $this->_getIdsByTags(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG, $tags);
    }

    /**
     * Return an array of metadatas for the given cache id
     *
     * The array must include these keys :
     * - expire : the expire timestamp
     * - tags : a string array of tags
     * - mtime : timestamp of last modification time
     *
     * @param string $id cache id
     * @return array array of metadatas (false if the cache id is not found)
     */
    public function getMetadatas($id)
    {
        $metadatas = $this->_getCache($this->_file($id), false);
        if ($metadatas) {
            $metadatas['tags'] = explode(',' ,$metadatas['tags']);
        }
        return $metadatas;
    }

    /**
     * Give (if possible) an extra lifetime to the given cache id
     *
     * @param string $id cache id
     * @param int $extraLifetime
     * @return boolean true if ok
     */
    public function touch($id, $extraLifetime)
    {
        $file = $this->_file($id);
        $cache = $this->_getCache($file, true);
        if (!$cache) {
            return false;
        }
        list($metadatas, $data) = $cache;
        if (time() > $metadatas['expire']) {
            return false;
        }
        $newMetadatas = array(
            'hash' => $metadatas['hash'],
            'mtime' => time(),
            'expire' => $metadatas['expire'] + $extraLifetime,
            'tags' => $metadatas['tags']
        );
        return !! $this->_filePutContents($file, serialize($newMetadatas)."\n".$data);
    }

    /**
     * Get a metadatas record and optionally the data as well
     *
     * @param  string $file  Cache file
     * @param  bool $withData
     * @return array|bool
     */
    protected function _getCache($file, $withData)
    {
        if (!is_file($file) || ! ($fd = @fopen($file, 'rb'))) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->_options['file_locking']) flock($fd, LOCK_SH);
        $metadata = fgets($fd);
        if ( ! $metadata) {
            if ($this->_options['file_locking']) flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
            fclose($fd);
            return false;
        }
        if ($withData) {
            $data = stream_get_contents($fd);
        }
        if ($this->_options['file_locking']) flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fd);
        $metadata = @unserialize(rtrim($metadata,"\n"));
        if ($withData) {
            return array($metadata, $data);
        }
        return $metadata;
    }

    /**
     * Get meta data from a cache record
     *
     * @param  string $id  Cache id
     * @return array|bool Associative array of meta data
     */
    protected function _getMetadatas($id)
    {
        return $this->_getCache($this->_file($id), false);
    }

    /**
     * Set a metadatas record
     *
     * @param  string $id        Cache id
     * @param  array  $metadatas Associative array of metadatas
     * @param  boolean $save     optional pass false to disable saving to file
     * @return boolean True if no problem
     */
    protected function _setMetadatas($id, $metadatas, $save = true)
    {
        // TODO - implement for unit tests ___expire method
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Return the complete directory path of a filename (including hashedDirectoryStructure)
     *
     * Uses multiple letters for a single-level hash rather than multiple levels
     *
     * @param  string $id Cache id
     * @param  boolean $parts if true, returns array of directory parts instead of single string
     * @return string|array Complete directory path
     */
    protected function _path($id, $parts = false)
    {
        $partsArray = array();
        $root = $this->_options['cache_dir'];
        $prefix = $this->_options['file_name_prefix'];
        if ($this->_options['hashed_directory_level']>0) {
            $root .= $prefix . '--' . substr(md5($id), -$this->_options['hashed_directory_level']) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            $partsArray[] = $root;
        }
        if ($parts) {
            return $partsArray;
        } else {
            return $root;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clean some cache records (protected method used for recursive stuff)
     *
     * Available modes are :
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL (default)    => remove all cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_OLD              => remove too old cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG     => remove cache entries matching all given tags
     *                                               ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_NOT_MATCHING_TAG => remove cache entries not {matching one of the given tags}
     *                                               ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG => remove cache entries matching any given tags
     *                                               ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     *
     * @param string $dir  Directory to clean
     * @param string $mode Clean mode
     * @param array $tags
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
     * @return boolean True if no problem
     */
    protected function _clean($dir, $mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, $tags = array())
    {
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            return false;
        }
        $result = true;
        $glob = @glob($dir . $this->_options['file_name_prefix'] . '--*');
        if ($glob === false) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach ($glob as $file)  {
            if (is_file($file)) {
                if ($mode == Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL) {
                    $result = @unlink($file) && $result;
                    continue;
                }

                $id = $this->_fileNameToId(basename($file));
                $_file = $this->_file($id);
                if ($file != $_file) {
                    @unlink($file);
                    continue;
                }
                $metadatas = $this->_getCache($file, false);
                if ( ! $metadatas) {
                    @unlink($file);
                    continue;
                }
                if ($mode == Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_OLD) {
                    if (time() > $metadatas['expire']) {
                        $result = $this->_remove($file) && $result;
                        $result = $this->_updateIdsTags(array($id), explode(',', $metadatas['tags']), 'diff') && $result;
                    }
                    continue;
                } else {
                    Zend_Cache::throwException('Invalid mode for clean() method.');
                }
            }
            if ((is_dir($file)) and ($this->_options['hashed_directory_level']>0)) {
                // Recursive call
                $result = $this->_clean($file . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $mode) && $result;
                if ($mode == 'all') {
                    // if mode=='all', we try to drop the structure too
                    @rmdir($file);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($mode == 'all') {
            foreach (glob($this->_tagFile('*')) as $tagFile) {
                @unlink($tagFile);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Clean some cache records (protected method used for recursive stuff)
     *
     * Available modes are :
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL (default)    => remove all cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_OLD              => remove too old cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG     => remove cache entries matching all given tags
     *                                               ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_NOT_MATCHING_TAG => remove cache entries not {matching one of the given tags}
     *                                               ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     * Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG => remove cache entries matching any given tags
     *                                               ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     *
     * @param  string $mode Clean mode
     * @param  array  $tags Array of tags
     * @throws Zend_Cache_Exception
     * @return boolean True if no problem
     */
    protected function _cleanNew($mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, $tags = array())
    {
        $result = true;
        $ids = $this->_getIdsByTags($mode, $tags);
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $idFile = $this->_file($id);
            if (is_file($idFile)) {
                $result = $this->_remove($idFile) && $result;
            }
        }
        switch($mode)
        {
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG:
                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    $tagFile = $this->_tagFile($tag);
                    if (is_file($tagFile)) {
                        $result = $this->_remove($tagFile) && $result;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_NOT_MATCHING_TAG:
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG:
                $this->_updateIdsTags($ids, $tags, 'diff');
                break;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $mode
     * @param array $tags
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getIdsByTags($mode, $tags)
    {
        $ids = array();
        switch($mode) {
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_NOT_MATCHING_TAG:
                $ids = $this->getIds();
                if ($tags) {
                    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                        if ( ! $ids) {
                            break; // early termination optimization
                        }
                        $ids = array_diff($ids, $this->_getTagIds($tag));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG:
                if ($tags) {
                    $tag = array_shift($tags);
                    $ids = $this->_getTagIds($tag);
                    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                        if ( ! $ids) {
                            break; // early termination optimization
                        }
                        $ids = array_intersect($ids, $this->_getTagIds($tag));
                    }
                    $ids = array_unique($ids);
                }
                break;
            case Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG:
                foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                    $ids = array_merge($ids,$this->_getTagIds($tag));
                }
                $ids = array_unique($ids);
                break;
        }
        return $ids;
    }

    /**
     * Make and return a file name (with path)
     *
     * @param  string $id Cache id
     * @return string File name (with path)
     */
    protected function _tagFile($id)
    {
        $path = $this->_tagPath();
        $fileName = $this->_idToFileName($id);
        return $path . $fileName;
    }

    /**
     * Return the complete directory path where tags are stored
     *
     * @return string Complete directory path
     */
    protected function _tagPath()
    {
        $path = $this->_options['cache_dir'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->_options['file_name_prefix']. '-tags' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        if ( ! $this->_isTagDirChecked) {
            if ( ! is_dir($path)) {
                if (@mkdir($path, $this->_options['use_chmod'] ? $this->_options['directory_mode'] : 0777) && $this->_options['use_chmod']) {
                    @chmod($path, $this->_options['directory_mode']); // see #ZF-320 (this line is required in some configurations)
                }
            }
            $this->_isTagDirChecked = true;
        }
        return $path;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|resource $tag
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getTagIds($tag)
    {
        if (is_resource($tag)) {
            $ids = stream_get_contents($tag);
        } elseif(file_exists($this->_tagFile($tag))) {
            $ids = @file_get_contents($this->_tagFile($tag));
        } else {
           $ids = false;
        }
        if( ! $ids) {
            return array();
        }
        $ids = trim(substr($ids, 0, strrpos($ids, "\n")));
        return $ids ? explode("\n", $ids) : array();
    }

    /**
     * @param array $ids
     * @param array $tags
     * @param string $mode
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _updateIdsTags($ids, $tags, $mode)
    {
        $result = true;
        if (empty($ids)) {
            return $result;
        }
        foreach($tags as $tag) {
            $file = $this->_tagFile($tag);
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                if ($mode == 'diff' || (rand(1,100) == 1 && filesize($file) > 4096)) {
                    $file = $this->_tagFile($tag);
                    if ( ! ($fd = fopen($file, 'rb+'))) {
                        $result = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ($this->_options['file_locking']) flock($fd, LOCK_EX);
                    if ($mode == 'diff') {
                        $_ids = array_diff($this->_getTagIds($fd), $ids);
                    } else {
                        $_ids = array_merge($this->_getTagIds($fd), $ids);
                    }
                    fseek($fd, 0);
                    ftruncate($fd, 0);
                    $result = fwrite($fd, implode("\n", array_unique($_ids))."\n") && $result;
                    if ($this->_options['file_locking']) flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
                    fclose($fd);
                }
                else {
                    $result = file_put_contents($file, implode("\n", $ids)."\n", FILE_APPEND | ($this->_options['file_locking'] ? LOCK_EX : 0)) && $result;
                }
            } else if ($mode == 'merge') {
                $result = $this->_filePutContents($file, implode("\n", $ids)."\n") && $result;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }


    protected function _filePutContents($file, $string)
    {
        $result = @file_put_contents($file, $string, $this->_options['file_locking'] ? LOCK_EX : 0);
        if ($result && $this->_options['use_chmod']) {
            @chmod($file, $this->_options['file_mode']);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Make the directory structure for the given id
     *
     * @param string $id cache id
     * @return boolean true
     */
    protected function _recursiveMkdirAndChmod($id)
    {
        if ($this->_options['hashed_directory_level'] <=0) {
            return true;
        }
        $partsArray = $this->_path($id, true);
        foreach ($partsArray as $part) {
            if (!is_dir($part)) {
                @mkdir($part, $this->_options['use_chmod'] ? $this->_options['directory_mode'] : 0777);
                if ($this->_options['use_chmod']) {
                    @chmod($part, $this->_options['directory_mode']); // see #ZF-320 (this line is required in some configurations)
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

how to solve this error?
Is **Magento 2.2** is not supported to **PHP 7.2.0**???

Comment: Please paste here your actual error. To check error on screen uncomment line #11 from app/bootstrap.php and set developer mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately no, **PHP 7.2** is not officially supported yet. You can see below list and information from Magento dev docs about the system requirements.

### 1. Magento 2.2.x supports PHP Versions below:

- 7.0.0, 7.0.1 - Not supported
- 7.0.2 - Supported
- 7.0.3 - Not supported
- 7.0.4 - Supported
- 7.0.5 - Not Supported
- 7.0.6–7.0.x   - Supported
- 7.1.x - Supported

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

### 2. Possible Fix:

As stated in the warning the `each()` function has become depreciated as of **PHP 7.2** you can see more information about this here:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php

To fix the error however you can try swapping the `each()` function with `foreach()` as this is supported in **PHP 7.2** but i cannot guarantee that more issues will begin to arise.

Comment: Not to mention `mcrypt` has been removed from PHP 7.2 so there are gonna be a lot more issues than can be fixed by just grepping `each()` ... I'd say until the `mcrypt` issue is sorted, Magento on PHP 7.2 is a no-go... still PHP 7.1 doesn't hit *end  of life* until Dec 2019 so there's time yet.

Comment: I used pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 to work around the mcrypt issue but decided to change php version for safety

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference for future visitors with a similar question about Magento and PHP version compatibility.
[image: Version-table]

References:

- https://gist.github.com/fooman/b1d70ca2954c05c3e11a7a9db04a8a10#file-table-md
- https://github.com/navarr/magento2-supported-versions/blob/master/README.md